# gnuplot command-line options

Tags: command-line, gnuplot

How to set 'Direct2D backend' option by default for "win" terminal in gnuplot 5.2.8? I know how to set this option interactively by clicking on the drop-off menu in a graph window.  Is it possible to set it in the command-line call to gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to set 'Direct2D backend' option to be the default with pm3d in gnuplot 5.2.8.  First, wgnuplot.ini file has to be generated using a gnuplot prompt. Second, the following line has to be deleted (if present): GraphGDI+=0 or GraphGDI+=1. Third, the following line has to be added to wgnuplot.ini file:  GraphD2D=1.  Save wgnuplot.ini file after editing and run gnuplot.  'Direct2D backend' option is set as default now.